# Firefox Extension Error (chrome.manifest)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, manifest

I'm doing a Firefox addon but I'm currently getting this error in the Error Console.

> Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/extensions/%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D/chrome.manifest'.

And of course the script doesn't load. Any suggestions?

**PS**: The `chrome.manifest` file exists and has the current code inside

```
content fbp chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes
overlay    chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://fbp/content/tracker.xul
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is unrelated to your extension. `{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}` is the ID of the default Firefox theme. And sure enough - it doesn't have a `chrome.manifest` file so [this warning comes up on every browser start](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586610). Just ignore the warning.

As to why your script doesn't load - that's a different question that is impossible to answer with the information provided.